# javascript hoisting for global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables, scope, hoisting

I was wondering how javascript hoisting works for global variable.

Let's say I have following code snippet:

```
var a = 5;
function print(){
    console.warn("a",a,b);
    var a = 10;
    b=5;
    console.warn("a",a);
}
print();
```

In this case I am getting error "b is not defined". I wonder why Javascript hoisting is not working for global variable. I tried to look for this but getting results only for variable hoisting. Any thoughts??

Comment: Basically: `b=5;` doesn't get hoisted. Only `var` statements do.

Comment: So when I say b=5, it has a global scope, so why it's not take from global scope.

Comment: thx alot, I learned a new thing about JavaScript :-) I also had a look at this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

Answer (score 4):

`var` statements are hoisted. function *declarations* are hoisted. Assignments are not hoisted (to the extent that if you combine a `var` statement with an assignment (`var foo = 1`) then the declaration part is hoisted but the assignment is not).

Comment: So when I say b=5, it has a global scope, so why it's not take from global scope.

Comment: @Mayank: The whole `b` variable _does not get hoisted_. This means, at the time of `console.warn("a",a,b);`, `b` does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is reinterpreted as:

```
function print(){
    var b
    console.warn("a",a,b); // b is not assigned yet so it's undefined.
    var a = 10;
    b=5;
    console.warn("a",a);
}
```